# Blazor class library, internal-only components

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor

I am creating a Blazor class library that has some Blazor components that will be referenced by other projects.

However, my class library also contains some Blazor components that I am using as helpers and would prefer it for them not to be able to be used by projects that reference my class library.

Is there a way I can prevent projects that reference my library from being able to use these components?

Comment: Have you tried declaring the classes `internal`? I could be wrong, but I don't believe razor requires the components to be public classes (unlike for example XAML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HH states, you can't do it using Razor components.

For the record, here's a simple example showing how you can using C# classes and `RenderTreeBuilder` code.

It's assembler for components - not for the faint hearted coder.

This is the code in a library project.

```cs
namespace Library;

internal class InternalComponent : ComponentBase
{
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "h1");
        builder.AddMarkupContent(1, $"Hello Blazor at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} ");
        builder.CloseElement();
    }
}

public class ExternalComponent : ComponentBase
{
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenComponent <InternalComponent>(0);
        builder.CloseComponent();
    }
}
```

And the demo `Index` page in the main project:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<Library.ExternalComponent />
```

See this MS article for more information on builder components using the `RenderTreeBuilder` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @HH - Something went wrong on the update to that [it posted a new answer for some reason].  Anyway, I've updated my answer to make `InternalComponent` internal.  It  works, which surprised me a little at first.  It's the Renderer that instantiates the class instances, but on reflection, it operates at a fairly low level where much of the high level stuff we are constrained by doesn't apply.

Comment: I'll have to retest that. When I tried this the MyComponent part was rendered as a html component.  Can you really see "Hello Blazor at ..." ?

Comment: "Hello Blazor at 13:26:41" where I am!

Comment: And I've just rechecked my code and It's definitely `protected`.

Comment: Interesting. I get the `Found markup element with unexpected name ...`  warning that I can toggle on/off with public/internal on that class.

Comment: @HH - pretty sure [but we're all fallible].  Repo is here. https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO76600414

Comment: OK, I see the difference. Your ExternalComp also uses BuildRenderTree(). If that's acceptable to the OP then this works.  But try to use it in a .razor file in your library. That will fail.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I'd rather avoid tangling with the component assembler so might just separate them by namespace

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, No.

When you use a `.razor` file then the Razor compiler generates a `public` class. You cannot override that.

And while you can create an `internal` component in a `.cs` file, and use code like `builder.OpenElement(0, "h1");`, the Razor compiler will not recognize those when used in other components.

I would use a special folder (namespace) in my library so that those 'internal' components are not automatically exposed in consumer code along with my 'main' components.